# Not able to install Node 10.x version in docker container

Tags: node.js, selenium, docker, ubuntu, npm

I have all the code to install nodejs 10.x verison inside ubuntu docker file, but its listing only the old version when am using node -v and not the latest one. PFB the dockerfile for more understanding

```
FROM selenium/node-chrome-x.x.x
RUN  curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install nodejs
RUN sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
RUN node -v
```

Expected output
Node version 10.x

Actual output
Node Version is 4.86

Please let us know how to setup the latest nodejs version and use it for other tool setup

Comment: what is this image name `selenium/node-chrome-x.x.x` ? It does not exist. x-x-x should be a tag i guess?

Comment: selenium/node-chrome:2.53.1

Comment: We have used that image for our regression setup for entire project , its actually a running image. So we are using that

Comment: Because I have just tested your Dockerfile with latest image and node version was upgraded to `v10.16.0`.

Comment: But using the same image, why am getting like below:                                            Removing intermediate container a12b4efb3dc0
Step 11/19 : RUN sudo node -v
 ---> Running in 7f1bffc9fba1
v4.2.6
 ---> 8b731d96fa79
Removing intermediate container 7f1bffc9fba1
Step 12/19 : RUN npm -v
 ---> Running in 945a8f3c20f3
3.5.2
 ---> 333da6a9d399

Comment: So you mean i need to use latest image as node is already upgraded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your Dockerfile and used image that you require. I had to install some dependencies like `curl` and so on. Also I just run one `RUN` command to create less intermediate layers :

```
FROM selenium/node-chrome:2.53.1

RUN sudo apt-get update &&\
    sudo apt-get -y install curl &&\
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash - &&\
    sudo apt-get -y install nodejs &&\
    sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node

RUN node -v
```

The output is :

```
v10.16.0
```